# Existence of a (19, 6, 1, 2) strongly regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

While reading [Is there a graph with 99 vertices...](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162583/is-there-a-graph-with-99-vertices-in-which-every-edge-belong-to-a-unique-triangl) I became curious about smaller graphs satisfying the property. According to Wikipedia, strongly regular graphs must satisfy the relation:

$$(v-k-1)\mu = k(k-\lambda-1)$$

If I computed correctly that would mean those graphs with $\lambda = 1$ and $\mu = 2$ must have $2n^2 + 1$ vertices and degree $2n$ (that would fit the $(99, 14, 1, 2)$ graph from the MO question with $n = 7$). $K_3$ trivially works, and for $(9, 4, 1, 2)$ we have the example [here](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~es/SRGs/9-4-1-2). The next candidate would be $(19, 6, 1, 2)$, but I couldn't find any mention of it. I'm not sure if that means that such an example doesn't exist, in which case I would be curious why, or if the existence is open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Any strongly regular graph on a prime number of vertices, must be a conference graph, which means that if it has $p$ vertices then its parameters are
$$
  p,\ \frac{p-1}2,\ \frac{p-5}4\, \frac{p-1}4.
$$
This is proved in the more recent of the books titled "Algebraic Graph Theory".

Andries Brouwer maintains a table of parameter sets of strongly regular graphs at http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/srg/srgtab.html; this is always a useful place to start.

For your particular case, if you compute the eigenvalues and their multiplicities,
you will arrive at a contradiction; more information about how to do this in the source cited above.